# Select an element if the href value is a specific word

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, megamenu

Hi and thanks in advance for your help!

I have previously used JS to add an active class to an element if the corresponding URL shows.

I am trying to take what I have done in the past and edit it.

I am trying to add an active class to an element if the href attribute equals '#tab1' for example. Rather than if the URL matches.

Please see the existing JS below that I am trying to work from, I have tried a few things including a getelementbyID rather than selecting the href but I'm lost.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const $links = $('.hs-mega-menu ul li a');
  $.each($links, function (index, link) {
    if (link.href == (document.URL)) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

An example of one of the nav-links I am trying to select and apply the active class too are below:

```
<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link g-py-10--md g-px-15--md" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Printed Stationery<i class="g-ml-10 fa-solid fa-caret-down d-sm-none"></i></a> </li>
```

Comment: `[href*="xxx"]`

Comment: @JaromandaX could you use this in my example above as a demonstration? I am struggling to replicate it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to add that to your selector? Not exactly that. Obviously the xxx is what you need.  And if you need an exact match remove the *

Comment: I did yes. At the moment its making every nav-link's href #tab1. Which in turn makes every single one active?

Comment: Add some *basic* debugging - check what `link.href` and `document.URL` *actually* are when you run the code, eg `console.log(link.href, document.URL)` - you might find one has "http://" or similar while the other doesn't.   So you need to revisit the `==` inside the `if` to match what you *actually* have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, you can use a function like you have or you can filter or just use a selector for the attribute.  Here are examples of the latter two.

```js
$(function() {
  let testurl = "#tab1";
  const $links = $('.hs-mega-menu ul li a');
  $links.filter(function(index, link) {
    return $(this).attr('href') == testurl;
  }).addClass("active");

  $links.filter("[href='" + testurl + "']").addClass("active-test")
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}

.active-test {
  background-color: #ffddff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hs-mega-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link g-py-10--md g-px-15--md" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Printed Stationery<i class="g-ml-10 fa-solid fa-caret-down d-sm-none"></i></a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link g-py-10--md g-px-15--md" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Printed Stationery<i class="g-ml-10 fa-solid fa-caret-down d-sm-none"></i></a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link g-py-10--md g-px-15--md" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Printed Stationery<i class="g-ml-10 fa-solid fa-caret-down d-sm-none"></i></a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```